# HP vertica SQL query to create new column

Tags: sql, database, vertica

This is the table I have and I have 5 distinct programs. when a user like a program it reads as follows:

```
User    Program     
----------------
    A   1   
    A   4   
    B   2   
    B   4   
    B   5
```

However I want to write a query that will allow me to also see the 5 distinct programs for each of my user and create a new column that will take two value (binary) 1 if the user liked a specific program and if not 0.   Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
User    Program     NewColumn

    A   1   1
    A   2   0
    A   3   0
    A   4   1
    A   5   0
    B   1   0
    B   2   1
    B   3   0
    B   4   1
    B   5   1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `cross join` and `left join`:

```
select u.user, p.program,
       (case when t.user is not null then 1 else 0 end) as NewCol
from (select distinct user from table) u cross join
     (select distinct program from table) p left join
     table t
     on u.user = t.user and p.program = t.program;
```

Note:  You may already have tables with the users and the programs.  If so, use those instead of the subqueries.

Comment: hi thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: I have implemented what you wrote and only return the previous table with new column is added with only 1.

Comment: @user5293636 . . . I got the alias wrong on the `case` expression.